# How can I uncover the content of the <header></header>?

Tags: html, css

I am unsure why my Navigation bar isn't showing up on this RGB MMA website, At the Top of the website there should be a title, 'RGB MMA' with a fixed nagivation bar with 4 headings that are written in the html of the code, 'Home' 'About' 'Join us' and 'Time table' I will post my html and css code below, Thank you for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>RGB MMA</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1> RGB MMA</h1>
        <nav> 
            <a href="#top"> home</a>
            <a href="#top"> About</a>
            <a href= "#join-us"> Join us!</a>
            <a href="#Timetable"> Timetable</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main id="top">
        <section class="feature image-mats">
            <div class="post-meta">
                <h2 class="post-meta_tagline"> Opening week</h2>
                <h1 class="post-meta_heading">Gym Tour</h1>
                <a class="post-meta_more" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="Join-us" class="feature image-striking">
            <div class="post-meta">
                <h2 class="post-meta_tagline">January plans available</h2>
                <h1 class="post-meta_heading">Join us today!</h1>
                <a class="post-meta_more" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="training-times" class="feature image-jits">
            <div class="post-meta">
                <h2 class="post-meta_tagline">Striking, grappling and MMA classes</h2>
                <h1 class="post-meta_heading">Class timetable</h1>
                <a class="post-meta_more" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer> RGB MMA @ 2024</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header
{
    position: fixed;
}
.image-mats
{
   background-image: url(https://dollamur.com/media/resized/620x345/wysiwyg/landing/lp_ma_block3_620x345.jpg) ;

}

nav
{
    display: flex;
    gap:2.3rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    align-items: center;
}

html, body, h1, h2
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: sans-serif
}

.feature
{
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;

}

section
{
    display: block;
}

.post-meta
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 3rem;
    color:white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.9rem;
}

.post-meta_tagline
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.post-meta_heading
{
    font-size:2.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-meta_more
{
    margin-top: 1.2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-transform :uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size: .85rem;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    opacity: 1;
    color:white;
    border:2px solid white;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.image-striking
{
    background-image: url(https://images.ctfassets.net/j4p65rou1yfw/4Pva6w46I8SRSDrOgtOMrF/a754139ac6589ce0f5b0897aa04323d9/ALTA_Training_-Chippendale_GP0785-COPY.webp);
}

.image-jits
{
    background-image: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5f8a56ba4e842e4e3ee85741/9fec8d22-92fe-4244-b80c-7e0274c84686/no-gi-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-classes-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-in-auburn.jpg) ;
}

footer
{
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: adding    z-index:+100000; on header should do the trick ...... its there but hidden behind other layers per say. just prefix the stacking order. This alternative to putting header tag the end pf code so it comes on top of stacking order, hence why we have z index

Comment: A massive `z-index` is not necessary unless you have 100000 layers. A simple  ` or 2 will do

Comment: @Paulie_D agree, massive numbers comes from old habits - nothing crossing that number :D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the stacking order by stating `position: relative` on `.feature`.

It's not really necessary so you can remove it. Alternatively, just give your `header` a `z-index: 2`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  //z-index:2;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-mats {
  background-image: url(https://dollamur.com/media/resized/620x345/wysiwyg/landing/lp_ma_block3_620x345.jpg);
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: center;
}

html,
body,
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.feature {
  //position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  display: block;
}

.post-meta {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 3rem;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.9rem;
}

.post-meta_tagline {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.post-meta_heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-meta_more {
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: .85rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.image-striking {
  background-image: url(https://images.ctfassets.net/j4p65rou1yfw/4Pva6w46I8SRSDrOgtOMrF/a754139ac6589ce0f5b0897aa04323d9/ALTA_Training_-Chippendale_GP0785-COPY.webp);
}

.image-jits {
  background-image: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5f8a56ba4e842e4e3ee85741/9fec8d22-92fe-4244-b80c-7e0274c84686/no-gi-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-classes-brazilian-jiu-jitsu-in-auburn.jpg);
}

footer {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> RGB MMA</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#top"> home</a>
    <a href="#top"> About</a>
    <a href="#join-us"> Join us!</a>
    <a href="#Timetable"> Timetable</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main id="top">
  <section class="feature image-mats">
    <div class="post-meta">
      <h2 class="post-meta_tagline"> Opening week</h2>
      <h1 class="post-meta_heading">Gym Tour</h1>
      <a class="post-meta_more" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="Join-us" class="feature image-striking">
    <div class="post-meta">
      <h2 class="post-meta_tagline">January plans available</h2>
      <h1 class="post-meta_heading">Join us today!</h1>
      <a class="post-meta_more" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="training-times" class="feature image-jits">
    <div class="post-meta">
      <h2 class="post-meta_tagline">Striking, grappling and MMA classes</h2>
      <h1 class="post-meta_heading">Class timetable</h1>
      <a class="post-meta_more" href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer> RGB MMA @ 2024</footer>
```